# How to detect window resize event when a browser moves between dual monitors

Tags: javascript, window-resize, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to detect window resize event when a browser moves between dual monitors?

`window.onresize` event does not seem to fire, when I drag the browser to a second screen, a refresh is required to force the `onresize` event

Is there any other event we can trap to detect when the browser moves from one screen to another (especially if they are of different resolution)

Comment: This works http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onresize

Comment: @partypete25 this totally works. Thanks

Comment: Why does the `onresize` event on `body` work but not on `window`?